# Submit form with only selected model attributes inside table (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. I have a  with a table where I present model attribute which is a list of objects. I present them in table rows using "th:each"
2. With every row, I present a checkbox, intending to mark some of the presented table rows
3. I want to submit the form and POST only the list of selected model attributes (only those in the selected table rows)

This is how I present the model attribute list of objects inside table rows (I skipped irrelevant parts of the code):

```
<form class="form-horizontal"
    th:action="@{'/supplier/define'}"
    th:object="${foundSuppliers}" th:method="POST">

.....
<tr th:each="supplier, iterStat : ${foundSuppliers.suppliersDTO}">
    <td class="hide" th:text="${supplier.id}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${supplier.name}">Name</td>
    <td><input th:id="'chk_' + ${supplier.id}"
            type="checkbox" th:field="*{foundSuppliers.suppliersDTO}" th:value="${supplier}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I submit this form, my "foundSuppliers.suppliersDTO" list is empty even though I check at least one row in my table.

My controller method behind specified th:action (of "form" tag) is:

```
public String defineSuppliers(@ModelAttribute SupplierListDTO foundSuppliers, Model model) { 
... 
}
```

**What should I do to actually populate foundSuppliers.suppliersDTO with a list of objects that I marked with checkbox?**

To clarify, "foundSuppliers" is a model attribute I pass from controller, and it contains a list of suppliers. The class that I pass as "foundSuppliers" looks like this:

```
public class SupplierListDTO {
    private List<SupplierDTO> suppliersDTO;
    .....
}
```

And I use the same one as th:object inside "form" tag, this is the list I want to pass to backend controller when form is submitted, except the list should contain only the objects inside table rows where I ticked the checkbox.

Comment: I edited my original question after reworking my code based on @GabiM's advice

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your entire table is enclosed in the same form (mind you, none of this code has been tested):

```
<form action="/....." method="POST">
<tr th:each="supplier : ${foundSuppliers}">
  <td class="hide" th:text="${supplier.id}">ID</td>
  <td th:text="${supplier.name}">Name</td>
  <td><input th:id="'chk_' + ${supplier.id}" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Then, on the controller side, you need a custom data binder converting your list of IDs to your domain objects.

```
@Component
public class IdToSupplierConverterFactory
implements ConverterFactory<String, Supplier> {
    private static class IdToSupplierConverter<Supplier> 
      implements Converter<String, Supplier> {

       @PersistenceContext
       private EntityManager em;

        public Supplier convert(String id) {
            return em.findById(id, Supplier.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <Supplier> Converter<String, Supplier> getConverter(
      Class<Supplier> targetType) {
        return new IdToSupplierConverter();
    }
}
```

Spring should do the rest and map your paramaters to:

```
 @PostMapping("/......")
 public YourType myControllerMethod(@RequestParam List<Supplier> suppliers) {
   return ...;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the table is enclosed in the <form>. So, you're saying I cannot pass the entire object without converter, although the object is already passed to my form as model attribute and as such presented in table rows?

Comment: I think so... because you are dealing with two requests - one to display the form and the other to post it... i don't think out of the box spring can recover the model objects passed on a previous request. but maybe someone knows better

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either through javascript or Spring Boot. Maybe the easiest way is to to give the your checkbox field a name and then retrieve it through your controller. This way, you can easily check if the value of that name/checkbox is null or not. You should come up with something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/supplier" , method = RequestMethod. POST)
public void getSuppliers(@RequestParam(value = "nameOfCheckBoxInThymeleaf", required = false) String checkboxValue) 
{
  if(checkboxValue != null)
  {
    // do some logic here - get a list of selected suppliers for example
  }
  else
  {
   // do some logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about the backend logic, that I got covered. The question is how to submit a list of selected "supplier" (as in list of model attribute objects which I selected).

Comment: My understanding is your have a table list in Thymeleaf whose rows include checkboxes. Say we have 5 rows with checkboxes and if somebody selects only 2 checkboxes our of these rows, that is what you want to retrieve in your controller ?

Comment: Not the checkboxes really, I want to retrieve the objects which I present in table rows, but only those objects that user marked by ticking the chekbox. I have a list of suppliers (per my code snippet), but a user wants to relate only some of them to his profile. I have to show all of them, but store only those that user has chosen by ticking the checkbox. So, what do I write in my HTML (or javascript) to make sure I pass a list of selected supplier objects to my controller

Comment: Ok so that is exactly what I am understanding. You first give your checkbox a name. Then you get this name through your spring boot controller and check if its value true (if it is true, this means the checkbox is checked). So if it is checked, then you do your logic to store only the checked ones...

Comment: That's fine, but how do I pass the selected list of objects? Like, when you submit say, user login form, in thymeleaf you would write something like this: <form th:action="@{/user/login}" method="post"> and in the form tag you will have, say  <input type="text" name="username" th:field="${userForm.username}"> <input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:field="${userForm.password}">. So, my question is, how I do this same thing when I have a list of objects I want to submit

Comment: I see now ! Check this example out: https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list . It is exactly what you are asking for... Let me know if it works out for you ?

Comment: In that example you have all the fields of the domain object present in the form while in the case in question we only have the object id and we need to recover the state of the object